# Breakpoints in UnitTest++

Tags: c++, debugging, breakpoints, unittest++

I'm creating some unit test with UnitTest++ in Codelite editor. However, when if i'm debuging my unit test application the breakpoints won't hit. They aren't even shown in debugging mode. Isn't it possible to debug UnitTest++ tests? Or what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it has probably something to do with CodeLite (or did you build the program without debugging capabilities?), in VS this works fine. Are you putting the breakpoint onto the CHECK macro? Maybe CodeLite doesn't allow you to put a breakpoint on a macro?

Comment: Thank's for your answer, I have places breakpoint on all possible kinds of rows. I have also compared the test project with one that works with breakpoints and I cant se any differences. In that case it looks like there is an CodeLite limitation.. and that sux!

Answer (score 1):

In order to debug your unit tests using UnitTest++ in Codelite, you can use "Quick Debug" from the "Debug" menu.

set the executable to be the Test Project output. Which should have been set to an executable by the UnitTest++ plugin already.

As you already know, you need to have a main class that will call the testRunner:

## main.cpp

```
#include <UnitTest++.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return UnitTest::RunAllTests();
}
```

The debugger should break at the first line of your main class and further breakpoints should work.

I hope this helps.